# Можно ли создавать и добавлять страницы в административной панели wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть одностраничная верстка, натянутая на WP.
Можно ли создавать свои страницы в админке и привязывать их к основной странице не залезая в код? Чтобы заказчик сам мог их создавать.

Если да, то как ? Направьте хотя бы в какую-то сторону

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под привязкой своих страниц к основной странице? Есть например [ACF Relationships](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

Comment: Основная страница имеется ввиду. Одна, единственная, главная, так как это одностраничник, но заказчик в дальнейшем будет создавать свои простые страницы на которые можно ссылаться, например через слайдер. Тыкая по слайду его должно будет перекидывать на его же одну ИЗ созданную страницу в WP

Comment: В таком случае ACF Relationships вполне подходит.

Comment: Благодарю, ознакомлюсь )

Comment: Никакой АЦФ тут не нужен. Всё есть из коробки.

Comment: @SeVlad Вы о парент/чайлд страницах?

Comment: @SeVlad расскажите поподробнее, коль в коробке все есть. Или статью в лицо мне швырните